# Copy & Paste Values in Same Location

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to macros and am having trouble creating a macro that will copy a range of cells and then paste just the values back into the same cells.  Basically I just need to get rid of the formulas and paste the value back into the same location.

I have tried the coding below, but I am getting an error that says "Run-time error '1004': PasteSpecial method of Range class failed."  Can anyone help?

```
Sub CopyPaste()
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:G105").Copy
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:G105").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:G105")
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

This will replace formulas with their values and is much faster than copy and special paste.